# Why is my variable undefined in the second if statement?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm trying to reuse the same variable in a second `if` statement from the first `if` statement and I get the warning that my variable is `undefined` when I throw an alert on it.

How could I make this variable retain its value on the second `if` statement? I'm only copying part of the code for you to see what I'm talking about. I am trying to use `foundRangeStart` in the second if statement for `ESNEnd`, which was previously used in the first `if` statement for `ESNStart`.

Why is `foundRangeStart` set to `undefined` in the second `if` statement?

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == "ESNStart") {
    var esnStart = [];
    esnStart[0] = esn_to_num(enteredData);
    var item;
    var rangesFoundStart = [];

    rangesFoundStart[0] = -1; // Set defaut value as -1 for the corresponding entry in the "rangesFound" array
    for (var x in ranges) { // Inner loop over items in ranges object
        item = esnStart[0];
        if (item >= ranges[x].min && item <= ranges[x].max) {
            rangesFoundStart[0] = x;
        }
    }

    if (rangesFoundStart[0] >= 0) {
        foundRangeStart = rangesFoundStart[0];
    }

    if (foundRangeStart && foundRangeStart >= 0) {
        $("#STxModel").val(ranges[foundRangeStart].StxName);
        $("#TxSpacing").val(ranges[foundRangeStart].rtumodel);
    }
}
if ($(this).attr("id") == "ESNEnd") {
    var esnEnd = [];
    esnEnd[0] = esn_to_num(enteredData);
    var item;
    var foundRangeEnd;
    var rangesFound = [];
    rangesFound[0] = -1; // Set defaut value as -1 for the corresponding entry in the rangesFound array
    for (var x in ranges) { // Inner loop over items in ranges object
        item = esnEnd[0];
        if (item >= ranges[x].min && item <= ranges[x].max) {
            if (rangesFound[x] == foundRangeStart) {
                rangesFound[0] = x;
                var foundone = rangesFound[0] = x;
                alert(foundone + foundRangeStart);
            }
        } else {
            alert(alert_total);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you declare something inside a conditional or object, it does not exist outside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in that control path, `foundRangeStart` has not been set.

It only appears to be set here, in the first `ESNStart` block;

```
if ( rangesFoundStart[0] >= 0 ) {  
    foundRangeStart = rangesFoundStart[0];
}
```

But that line is not executed if this statement does not equal `true`;

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == "ESNStart") { ... }
```

Comment: how would u go about fixing it so the second if statement can pick up its value ?/

Comment: I wouldn't, you would though. I have no idea what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use `foundRangeStart` in the second if statement for ESNEnd, which was previously used in the first if statement for ESNStart

No, it was not used in the first if-statement. If the second one is executed, the first one was not - the two conditions `$(this).attr("id") == "ESNStart"` and `$(this).attr("id") == "ESNEnd"` are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if ( rangesFoundStart[0] >= 0 ) {  
            foundRangeStart = rangesFoundStart[0];
         }
```

You're declaring the variable inside a conditional. What if rangesFoundStart[0] is less than 0? Then the variable would never have been declared.

You can fix this by declaring foundRangeStart outside of the conditional.

```
       var rangesFoundStart = [];
       var foundRangeStart;

            rangesFoundStart[0] = -1; // Set defaut value as -1 for the corresponding entry in the "rangesFound" array
            for (var x in ranges) { // Inner loop over items in ranges object
                item = esnStart[0];
                if (item >= ranges[x].min && item <= ranges[x].max) {
                     rangesFoundStart[0] = x;
                }
            }

        if ( rangesFoundStart[0] >= 0 ) {  
            foundRangeStart = rangesFoundStart[0];
         }
```

Comment: That's no declaration at all.

Comment: @infinityLoop it still doesn't fix it.